# Converting a variable stored in a list into a list of character vectors in r

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, type-conversion, element

I have a subset of data that originates from a very large dataset.  I have split this subset of data into a list of dataframes so that each case/id is a separate element within the list. Each element is named with the case/id.   I then remove all variables from each dataframe element to be left with only one variable - called 'state'.  It is currently a factor with 7 levels.

I am attempting to turn this list of 'state' elements into a list of character vectors.  The element below is the first in the list, and included are the row numbers (which originate from the much larger original dataset).

```
[[1]]
        state
104246 active
104247   rest
104248 active
104249 active
.
.
.
104315 active
104316 active
104317   rest
104318   rest
```

I am trying to turn this simply into a character vector that would look like this:

```
[1] "active" "rest" "active" "active" ........... "active" "active" "rest" "rest"
```

It seems simple.  I have tried doing things like (where 'temp' is the list name):

```
as.vector(as.matrix(temp))
```

This returns something like this:

```
         [,1]  
    id1  List,1
    id2  List,1
    id3  List,1
    id4  List,1
```

When I look at each element from this they basically appear to be still in longform.

Alternatively, I tried directly converting to a character:

```
as.vector(as.character(temp))
```

But, this comes back as not the ideal format (though, I guess I could hack this to convert the factor level numbers to words...  (note in the large dataset, there are 7 levels of the factor 'state')

```
[1] "list(state = c(1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4,     1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1,     1, 1, 1, 4, 4))"
```

I also tried making the variable 'state' which is a factor a character variable prior to conversion, but that didn't help.

Here is the data for a reproducible example. It contains two elements in the list 'temp' only in this example:

```
temp<-list(structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
                                           6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("active", "active2", "active3", "rest", "rest2", 
                                                                   "stop", "stop2"), class = "factor")), .Names = "state", row.names = 104246:104318, class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("active", "active2", 
                                                                                   "active3", "rest", "rest2", "stop", "stop2"), class = "factor")), .Names = "state", row.names = 950:977, class = "data.frame"))



str(temp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L = lapply(temp, function(x) as.character(unlist(x)))` Just `L[[1]]` or `L[[2]]` for the vectors.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a good opportunity to use `rapply`:

```
x <- rapply(temp, as.character, how = "replace")
str(x)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ state: chr [1:73] "active" "rest" "active" "active" ...
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ state: chr [1:28] "active" "rest" "rest" "rest" ...
```

If you wanted to flatten it out further, then you can use `unlist(..., recursive = FALSE)`.

```
str(unlist(rapply(temp, as.character, how = "replace"), recursive=FALSE))
# List of 2
#  $ state: chr [1:73] "active" "rest" "active" "active" ...
#  $ state: chr [1:28] "active" "rest" "rest" "rest" ...
```

---

This second approach would give you the same results as @Vlo's approach, but would be more efficient than it calls `unlist` just once. To see how different it could be, here's are some benchmarks on a larger `list`:

```
x <- replicate(1000, temp)   ## A larger list

## Vlo's approach
fun1 <- function() {
  lapply(x, function(y) as.character(unlist(y, use.names = FALSE)))
} 

## My approach
fun2 <- function() {
  unlist(rapply(x, as.character, how = "replace"), 
         recursive=FALSE, use.names=FALSE)
} 

## Benchmarking
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), times = 50)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun1() 435.84992 475.17146 497.63325 533.68488 1570.6814    50
#  fun2()  50.90449  55.79023  63.85908  70.78956  111.0357    50

## Comparison of results
all.equal(fun1(), fun2(), check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
as.vector(unlist(temp[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code: `temp1 = temp[[1]][[1]]`. Here, `temp1` will be a list of characters.

MWE:

```
abc = data.table(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
temp = list(abc[, 'x'])[[1]][[1]]

> temp
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```